# Multiple check on string and to make different actions

Tags: bash, grep

I want to make multiple check depend on the result to make different actions.

In that case something is going wrong:

```
ssh 10.1.1.1 'sapi=`ps -ef | grep weblogic | grep sapi | grep -v grep | wc -l`;if [ ! $sapi ]; then printf "unknown";elif [ "$sapi" == "0" ]; then printf "inactive";else printf "active";fi'
```

The idea is when sapi string turn back:

```
0 - result to be inactive
1 or other kind of number - active
if is turn back nothing - to give unknown status
```

Comment: what is wrong? what is the problem?

Comment: With `ps` you can test if service is running or not (and count number of them). You me need another test if server you try to `ssh` to is down.

Comment: the problem is that not working, when turn no result give me inactive not unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`.  Here is an example from some of my older posts.

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$(ps -ef | awk '/[w]eblogic/ && /sapi/ {a++} END {print a+0}')" in

0)  echo "0 found"
    ;;
1)  echo "1 found"
    ;;
*)  echo "more than 1 found"
    ;;
esac
```

I did also simplified your test some.
PS you should not use old and outdated back-tiks, use parentheses `var=$(awk 'some code')`